# undefined reference to `UNITY_BEGIN' and 'UNITY_END'

Tags: c, unit-testing, gcc, makefile, linker

I want to use [Unity](http://www.throwtheswitch.org/unity/) for making unit test on my C code but I get the following error when compiling:

```
$ make
gcc  ../Unity/src/unity.o src/helpers.o src/chess.o src/search.o test/TestCheck.o src/main.o -o checkai
src/main.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x4b): undefined reference to `UNITY_BEGIN'
main.c:(.text+0x55): undefined reference to `UNITY_END'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:11: checkai] Error 1
$ make -n
gcc  ../Unity/src/unity.o src/helpers.o src/chess.o src/search.o test/TestCheck.o src/main.o -o checkai
```

My main functon just looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "helpers.h"
#include "chess.h"

#include "../../Unity/src/unity.h"
//#include "../test/TestCheck.h"

void test_Smoke(void) {
    TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL_INT(1, 2);
}

int main() {
    version();

    chesspiece chessboard[8][8];
    initField(chessboard);

    UNITY_BEGIN();
    RUN_TEST(test_Smoke, 1);
    return UNITY_END();
}
```

Do I link something incorrectly? I already tried to change the order of the gcc command but nothing has helped yet.
When I comment out `UNITY_BEGIN` and `UNITY_END` I can compile it and the smoke test runs without problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve it by not using the release version 2.1.0.
To solve it I have cloned the current master branch and it just worked even with `UNITY_BEGIN` and `UNITY_END`:

```
git clone https://github.com/ThrowTheSwitch/Unity.git
```